# Thread limit exceeded replacing blocked worker

Tags: java, http, asynchronous, asynchttpclient

I am using [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client), and making many http requests in parallel.
I am getting the following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Thread limit exceeded replacing blocked worker
```

How can I make a behavior where a new request waits until there is a free thread?

My code:

```
public class MyClass {
    private AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient();

    public JSONObject jsonFromUrl(String requestUrl) {
        CompletableFuture<Response> futureResponse = asyncHttpClient.prepareGet(requestUrl).
                addHeader("header-name", "header-value").execute().toCompletableFuture();
        try {
            Response response = futureResponse.get();
            ... handling response
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ... handling exception
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement and set a RejectedExecutionHandler for the thread pool that handles rejected tasks by adding them to the work queue of the executor.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionHandler.html

```
threadPoolExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable task, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        try {
            executor.getQueue().put(task);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
});
```

Note that in the implementation above *put()* is a blocking operation, meaning if the queue is full it waits until there's room again to insert the task.